# Changes to Markdown highlighting

Tags: discussion

The markdown help states:-

```
> Create a blockquote by
> prepending “>” to each line.
```

This used to produce a yellow background - making it particularly useful for highlighting warnings etc.
Now it produces an ugly grey sidebar (although I note the markdown help still seems to use the previous behaviour)

I also use the StackExchange app on my iPad and noticed that the highlighting still works there!

> text I would like to highlight

Is it possible to revert to the former?

I also use the official Stack Exchange iOS App on my iPad and this shows the yellow highlighting!

Comment: I can't stand the new "blends right in with everything else" code formatting.  I dunno if we can customize that stuff.  I can look into this (anyone can ask about it on Meta.SE, also)...ping me here overnight (aka, daytime down under) so I  remember to do tomorrow.